# How to pass data to http create server callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a Java developer learning NodeJS, and struggling with the basics here.

```
var sys = require("sys"),
    myhttp = require("http");

myhttp.createServer(callback).listen(8082);   //How do I pass a String here ?

function callback(request,response) {
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("msg");   //I want to access the string value being passed above
    response.end();
}
```

In the response.write line of code, I want to pass something dynamically. Not harcoded. The easy way is to make a global variable and use it, but I want to learn how to pass a string while passing the callback function (in the myhttp.createServer line). I tried looking at the source code of createServer method, but could not grasp a way to pass additional parameters.

Comment: callback.message="hello world"; (there is no passed data). you could also use bind() to set data as  _this_.

Comment: 2 downvotes ! Please let me know the reason. Are these questions too easy to be asked on SO ?

Comment: @dandavis : If I do callback.message = "hello world", can you please share how am I supposed to access that message in the callback function ?

Comment: if you define callback() in the createServer() callback, then you can basically use "callback.message" anywhere inside that outer function, or in the callback; each _callback_ function/object will be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want a factory that creates servers?

```
var sys = require("sys"),
    myhttp = require("http");

function makeServer(str) {
  myhttp.createServer(callback).listen(8082);

  function callback(request,response) {
      response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      response.write(str);
      response.end();
  }
}
```

More often you'd want to do some sort of data fetching inside your callback, or use a higher-order function to create the handler.

EDIT: based on your comment, you can also use a callback constructor by returning a function:

```
var sys = require("sys");
var myhttp = require("http");

function makeCallback(str) {
  return function(request, response) {
      response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      response.write(str);
      response.end();
  }
}

myhttp.createServer(makeCallback('foo')).listen(8082);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want to make a factory. As I said I am just learning by experiments. A more suitable usecase would be a "common/generic" callback function which can be used by multiple "client" functions (like http.createServer). In such cases the "clients" may like to have specific messages to be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Basically problem turns out to be how to inject parameter to function dynamically. Following is my attempt:

```
var sys = require("sys"),
    myhttp = require("http");

myhttp.createServer(function(request,response){
  var mystr = 'your dynamic value';
  callback(request, response, mystr); // injecting value using custom function
}).listen(8082);   //How do I pass a String here ?

function callback(request,response, str) {
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("msg");   //I want to access the string value being passed above
    response.end();
}
```

This is simple and quick solution in my opinion, i am still in learning mode and i welcome if someone edit my solution with more classy answer.